# Java library for tweets searching

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j, topsy

I'm wondering what is the best solution to retrieve tweets using a java library.

I used [twitter4j](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html), but I'm searching a library that has the following features or some of them:

- get tweets older than a week
- geolocation search by latitude and longitude
- search by date and specific time of the day
- search by hashtag (optional)

I also found service like [topsy](http://topsy.com/tweets) hat seems useful for my purpose, but I don't know if there is an update JAVA library for it.

Answer (score 0):

Topsy has json API. (http://api.topsy.com/doc/, http://api.topsy.com/doc/resources/content/tweets/)

You can use a json parser to parse the response. http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/restfull-java-client-with-java-net-url/, https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Also note the cost of topsy:

Cost:

Basic: $1.25 per thousand tweets

Enriched: $2.50 per thousand tweets